# How to get past "sending 'system' (92311 KB)..." when installing ubuntu on Nexus 7

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I'm in the process of installing the Ubuntu image onto my Nexus 7 following [these](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Flashing_the_device) directions.

I am on the step 4 and typed in `phablet-flash -b` and it downloaded some files, erased 'system' and is now on

```
sending 'system' (92311 KB)...
```

However, it has been on this step for about 3 hours now.  I am assuming it shouldn't take this long so how can I go about getting out of this and restarting the flash without bricking my device?

Answer (score 1):

If the system is stuck, you can safely start over albeit you will have to do it manually.

I'm going to say with a high degree of confidence that the devices that provide a fastboot interface and more so all the Nexus devices are mostly unbrickable unless you flash the **bootloader**, notice that I say **bootloader** and not the *boot* image.

So to start from scratch, reboot the device into *fastboot* once more. You can do so by pressing power and holding the Volume up and down keys all at the same time.

Locate your image files, I will shortly refer to them as `system.img`, `boot.img` and `recovery.img` from which I am omitting the device specific tag (`grouper` in the case of the *Nexus 7* for a more generic answer).

Once you locate them just run:

```
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash boot boot.img
```

Optionally flash the `recovery.img` which `phablet-flash -b` does for you anyways:

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

Then boot into recovery

```
fastboot boot recovery.img
```

Once in recovery, locate the *Ubuntu* side of the install, the file should be named `saucy-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip` (given that you are working on an unflipped model, the flipped/unflipped will make more sense in the following days from the date of this post). Push this so it is deployed by recovery:

```
adb push saucy-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip /sdcard/autodeploy.zip
adb reboot recovery
```

It should be mostly done after this.